# for loop with $http.get .then method

Tags: angularjs

before in Angular, I was using `.success` with `$http.get`... Inside the `.success`, I was able to do the following:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetUser')
.success(function (result) {
    $scope.users = result;
    if (result != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                sumeArray[i] = result[i].Id; 
            }
    }
})
.error(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now, with `.then`, I am not able to use the same `for loop` again.

My question is, is the `result.length` changed? How can I do similar to this?

Answer (score 2):

`.then` does not return the result directly, it returns the response.

The results are in `response.data`:

```
.then(function(response){
     var result = response.data;
     // Now it's the same
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But, can I after that use `response.data.length`? I want to perform `for loop` inside .then to fill an array

Comment: Yes, you can do so.